# Spinner not showing on device but is on emulators

Tags: android, spinner, emulation, device, missing-data

My initial 'home' activity in my android App has a spinner populated from a database. On the emulator this works absolutely fine. When I have my phone connected to the computer and run the app it also works fine. However, when it runs on my phone standalone (i.e. without being connected to Android Studio) the spinner does not show when i first open the app. However, if i exit that activity and return to it, or even restart the activity by changing the screen orientation, the spinner appears and is there until the app is closed. I have tried on a couple of phones with the same result. I have matched emulators to my phone's API and resolution but cannot replicate the bug. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
public class StartPage extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

String testusername;
String mUser;
int mPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


   //get reference to database helper
    SQLiteOpenHelper deadly60DatabaseHelper = new Deadly60DatabaseHelper(this);
    //get reference to database (read access)
    SQLiteDatabase db = deadly60DatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    //return all records in username table
    Cursor cursor = db.query("USERLIST", new String[] {"_id","USERNAME"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    //String temp = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);

    //put contents of cursor into an array list
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"))); //add the item
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    //find position of user just added or played in cursor so that can default to this in drop down spinner
    if(bundle != null){
        String user = bundle.getString("USERNAME");
        mUser = user;
        mPosition = mArrayList.indexOf(mUser);
    }
        else{
        mPosition=0;
        mUser = mArrayList.get(0);
    }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.usernamespinner);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, // context
            R.layout.my_spinner, // layout file
            cursor, // DB cursor
            new String[]{"USERNAME"}, // data to bind to the UI
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, // views that'll represent the data from `fromColumns` 
            0
    );

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown);
    //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelected(true);
    spinner.setSelection(mPosition); //set the selected user to the user just added or played
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code and your layout?

Comment: have just added java code

Comment: What do you do in `onResume()`?

Comment: i don't have an onResume() but as it's worked on the emulator and the issue is on startup of the app it's never seemed to have been required

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem. I don't see anythingh specifically wrong. You might want to delay the initialization of the spinner until `onResume()` and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look into how to do that. i did wonder if it was something to do with timing and left it on the same screen for a while but it still didn't appear, maybe not that kind of timing issue!

Comment: I would be inclined to troubleshoot this by taking a step back and commenting out the code that populates the spinner from the database. That way you can see at which stage this strange bug is being introduced. Does the spinner appear on your disconnected phone if the spinner is empty or has an item added to it from a simple arraylist?

Comment: It could be that forcing your `screenOrientation` to be portrait makes a difference if this is some kind of state issue.